# What are the differences among xamarin.forms' fontSizes?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, text, label

I am trying to decide which font size should I use for buttons, titles, tabs, etc. I know I have to use namedSizes in order to make the text dynamic.
I also know the definitions and recommendations given by Microsoft in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.namedsize?view=xamarin-forms)
but when I implement them there are ultimately only 4 or 5 sizes and multiple namedSizes always display the same sizes no matter the configuration specified in the phone's settings.
For example, Header, medium, and Default set the same text size, Large and Title also do the same.

I feel that there is something I am missing, could someone tell me if there is any real difference between these namedSizes?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is explicitly covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts#understand-named-font-sizes)

```
Member      iOS Android     UWP
Default     17  14          14
Micro       12  10          15.667
Small       14  14          18.667
Medium      17  17          22.667
Large       22  22          32
Body        17  16          14
Header      17  96          46
Title       28  24          24
Subtitle    22  16          20
Caption     12  12          12
```